# bootstrap navbar change active li background color manually

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have bootstrap navbar which is fixed and have body padding-top: 50px;
so far so good but the bootstrap.js and .css files make clicked li background color to be white and i want it to be black i guess the default is white.So i tried to manually change background-color property of the .active class

HTML:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Sales</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cogs"></span> Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

in custom CSS i have but nothing happens it does not change from white to black:

```
.active {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the navbar class.. [http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_inverse&stacked=h]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just changing the background of the `.active` class will not work

try the following:

```
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:focus, ul.nav a:active { color: #000; }
```

I don't thing `!important` will be necessairy

Comment: thank you! this code did the work

ul.nav a:focus, ul.nav a:active { background-color: black; }

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer as the right answer so there are no unnecessary open questions hanging on Stack.